# EF 4.3 Code first (migrations) with remote database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, frameworks, entity, code-first

I would like to use Code First approach in my MVC3 web application, so I found this tutorial
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/01/12/ef-4-3-beta-1-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx
Everything was OK untill I used database on localhost, but i really need to use database on my hosting, so i added connection string to my web.config:

```
    <add name="BlogContext"
     connectionString="data source=mssql4.webio.pl,2401;initial catalog=koki_forumMVC;user id=koki_administrator;password=MY_PASSWORD;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

My Context Class and Entity Class:

```
public class BlogContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
}
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }       
}
```

When i don't defined connection string when application starts, database is creating on local instance of sqlexpress. I'll be glad if it happens too when i define connection string to my remote server. I need to mentioned that when i exec command update-database in nuget console, if database is empty, my model is mapped to database. the problem is when i try to change my model by insert new property. when i execute cmd update-database i take error msg that the object with the same name of my model is founded in DB; /